# Link To Go To A Specific Area of a Page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

**How** do I go to a certain area of a scrolling page via a link? I can't quite figure out how, and Google won't turn up anything. Please Help! I've tried everything I could think of.

Comment: `<a href="#id-of-item-to-jump-to">Link</a>` then an html element with the same ID: `<div id="id-of-item-to-jump-to">Jump to me!</div>`

Comment: Thanks I think I got this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it.

```
<div id="here"></div>


<a href="#here"> go up top</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by ".here"? What I mean is how do you get the link URL

Comment: if the place you want to go to is an id use # before the id name. If the place you want to go to is a class you a period . before the class name.

Answer (score 1):

As alain already said, you can use href=".classname"

You could also go for href="#id"

I'd preffer the id over the class, Cause you can only assign an id once, wich will lower the chance on errors.